# IP setting on a windows

Tags: windows, windows-7, ip, windows-vista, desktop

I am working at a job site that i am setting up a jumbo sign and i am trying to figure out if there is a way to set a ip for a wifi on a windows PC and when you log off that wifi it will go away, but when you come back on the wifi it will set the ip back to where it was?

The PC is running windows 7 and one is running vista

Answer (score 2):

If I understand what you are asking for correctly, you can add an "alternate Configuration." Simply go to the properties of your NIC card select "Internet Protocol Version 4" select "Properties" and click the "Alternate Configuration Tab"

Answer (score 2):

Set the IP address, etc manually on the Wifi connection how you normally would. Set up the connection to automatically connect to the access point when it sees it.

In a logoff script, add the following line (replacing 'interface name' obviously:

```
netsh interface set interface <interface name> DISABLED
```

In a logon script, add the following line:

```
netsh interface set interface <interface name> ENABLED
```